# Constraintlayout animation with bottom tab

Tags: android, animation, parallax, android-constraintlayout

I have a tab, at the bottom of the page, 4 items in the tab. When I click an item in a tab a new page animates(like in parallax animation) from bottom to the top with this tab layout as the top item. How can I do this. Is it possible with contraintLayout?

Answer (score 0):

use FrameLayout which will act as fragment container and perform fragment transaction to stick fragment inside frame layout when user click on bottom tab item. 
Further you can also perform animations like bottom_up animation with that particular fragment.Make sure you are using that frame layout within activity_main.xml inside parent view where you want to show your animation.